# Différence entre « sur » et « au-dessus »

Tags: sens, prépositions, indications-de-lieu

Comment expliquer à un étudiant débutant la différence entre "sur" et "au-dessus".

"La bouteille est sur la table" semble beaucoup plus naturel que "La bouteille est au-dessus de la table", mais existe-t-il un semblant de règle qui permette de savoir quand utiliser l'un ou l'autre ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En général, j'utilise "sur" quand c'est en contact (posé sur la table). Si ce n'est pas en contact alors "au-dessus" (la lumière au-dessus de la table.)

Ceci dit, dans une pile, au-dessus de la pile c'est la chose que l'on peut voir (les autres choses étant cachées en dessous de la chose qui est au-dessus.)

Et le mot "sur" dans le cas d'une pile c'est soit une chose différente (j'ai vu les clefs sur la pile de livres) ou l'action d'ajouter quelque chose sur la pile (je pose mon livre sur cette pile [de livres].)

Hmmm... Bonne question!

Comment: "au-dessus de la pile c'est la chose que l'on peut voir (les autres choses étant cachées en dessous de la chose qui est au-dessus.)" Personellement, *au-dessus de la pile* a le même sens que *au dessus de la table*: si ça touche la pile, c'est *sur le dessus de la pile*.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec Circeus, si c'est dans la pile, je pense qu'on peut dire qu'un livre est "sur le dessus de la pile", mais que "au-dessus" c'est forcément hors de la pile.

Comment: En complément, il y a une différence entre _être sur quelqu'un_ qui est à prendre au sens premier du terme, alors qu'_être au dessus de quelqu'un_ est souvent au sens figuré, lui être supérieur

Comment: On dirait que Yves, qui a lui aussi donné une réponse, a le même sentiment que moi à propos d'une pile (ou d'un tas). Ceci dit, je suis d'accord que le premier sense de "au-dessus" est "sans contact".

Answer (score 8):

**Sur :** avec contact (anglais "on")

**Au-dessus de** / **dessus** (plutot suranné):

- sans contact (l'oiseau vole au dessus de la maison)
- avec contact mais sans pouvoir être inclus
- le dernier élément d'une pile d'un tas, ou celui qui est visible (J'ai mis le dossier urgent au dessus de la pile), anglais "on top of"

**Au-dessus :** Indication de direction familière, désignant souvent l'étage supérieur. (Où est Papa? Au-dessus, il bricole au grenier.)

Comment: *Au-dessus* n'a rien de familier.

Comment: non mais elle s'emploie surtout dans un contexte familier parce qu'elle est plutôt floue (comme indication de direction)